# CatBoost __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'silent'

Tags: python, catboost

all,

I do not understand the error I get when using CatBoost model. The issue appears here

```
model = CatBoost(silent=True)
```

returning the error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'silent'
```

I do not get why. Could anybody explain, please?

Thanks

Comment: What is not clear about the error message? There is no such argument as `silent` you can pass to construct a `CatBoost` instance.

Comment: From this I understood I can use silent as a parameter, read below: CatBoost has several parameters to control verbosity. Those are verbose, silent and logging_level.

By default logging is verbose, so you see loss value on every iteration. If you want to see less logging, you need to use one of these parameters. It's not allowed to set two of them simultaneously.

silent has two possible values - True and False.

Comment: See https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost.html

Comment: @selcuk, thank you!